# Turn "foreach" into "for" with structures

Tags: php

I have this block that prints some description and some product details.

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
  <tr>
    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I want to turn this into printing the description and only a number of product details so what I did is this

```
<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i <=4; $i++) {
    print_r($_additional[$i]);
  }
?>
```

This prints only the description though. How can I also print the product details?

Thank you

Comment: Please add an example of `$_additional` to the question, and clarify exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Is `$_additional` an array, or something else?  What does that `print_r` show?

Comment: Looks like $_additional is an associative array but in the second example you are trying to iterate through it like a numeric array. Can you do this: var_dump($_additional); exit; before the foreach loop and see what you get ?

Comment: $_additioinal generates all product attributes dynamicly. That block I posted brings as output the products description and all of its Additional Information. (weight, length etc)

I want to show just a number of those additional information and not all of them

Comment: Look at the answer from Fake51 and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the details of the array with

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i <=4; $i++) {
  echo $_additional[$i]['label'];
  echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_additional[$i]['value'], $_additional[$i]['code']);
}
```

Comment: This does not work either. It shows the description but not the product information. It shows exactly what my version did.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your $_additional object as a dump. seems like it's an array of arrays. But the issue you're having doesn't make sense if that is the case (because Fake51's response would work.) Can you die(print_r($_additional)); and paste the output to your question?